# Checking if string satisfies pattern

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.6

I am starting learning Python and i have problem with regex and python.

I want to check if word prefix is "aa" and suffix"bb". But i can only check prefix. Could you write some simple regexp for checking prefix and suffix is satisfied.

```
bool(re.match(regexp, word))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without regex:

```
word.startswith("aa") and word.endswith("bb")
```

or with regex:

```
bool(re.match("^aa.+bb$", word))
```